# How to detach exe from process

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

How can I detach an executable file from its process using WinAPI (C/C++)?

I found an application that releases files from processes, Unlocker, but I don't know how that works.

Comment: [What is your actual problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/158958)

Comment: I don't know, if it would work, but you can retrieve all the handles, associated with the process and close them.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  A process can't be detached from its executable.  As tenfour asked, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Lol4t0: I don't believe there's any way for a user-mode application to close another application's handles.

Comment: @CareyGregory, well, I think it is possible, if you get some privileges. I googled little before posting comment and found [this link](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/05/16/close-win32-handle-from-external-process/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't, normally. Windows pages in your executable on-demand. When you call a function which isn't in RAM yet, Windows loads it (and the whole page it resides on).

As a result, if you would detach the EXE and the process would call a function that's still on disk, the process would crash.

For applications on removable media, there's a special `/SWAPRUN:CD` linker flag. It prevents the crash by making a copy of the whole executable.